# Boostrap d-xl-block password hide/show problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made d-xl-block, d-sm,block .... by copying the form I wrote in Bootstrap 5-6 times according to dimensions. While the hide/show password function works in SM size, it only changes the eye image in other sizes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo2.png" type="img/logo2.png /">
    <title>Kayıt Ol</title>
</head>
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
    :root{
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body{
        font-family: var(--font-style);
        background-image: url('img/logo_background_2.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 110%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .pass {
        position: relative;
        left: 53%;
        bottom: 30px;
    }
    /* Animation */
    .h1,h4,p{
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38));
        
    }
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.animated {
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
    opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
    
</style>
<body >
<?php 
    include ("loginAndRegisterTitle.php"); 
?>
<br>

<form class="d-block d-sm-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-100 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-sm-block animated d-md-none animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-75 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
 
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-xl-block animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
<br>

    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script>
        function parolaGoster(id, el) {
          let x = document.getElementById(id);
          if (x.type == "password") {
            x.type = "text";
            el.className = 'fa fa-eye-slash parola pass';
          } else {
            x.type = "password";
            el.className = 'fa fa-eye parola pass';
          }
        }

</body>
</html>
```

Looking forward to your help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same password field over and over. Your JavaScript function searches the first password field (because you're searching by ID, of which only one should (and can) exist).

Merging the forms from this:

```
<form class="d-block d-sm-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-100 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-sm-block animated d-md-none animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-75 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
 
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  
        
</form>

<form class="d-none d-xl-block animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-50 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
<br>

    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

to this:

```
<form class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp container text-center my-4 w-100 mx-auto " action="conn.php" method="POST" style="color:white;">
    <br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">Şifre</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="sifre" name="sifre" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi belirleyin." required> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye parola pass" onClick="parolaGoster('sifre', this)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

        
</form>
```

should fix your problems.

Btw: Those classes (d-sm-none, d-md-block etc) can all be set on the same element. You could hide and show certain blocks on certain screen sizes, but you should never duplicate a piece of code for a different screen size with bootstrap.

Comment: I know that the problem is solved in this way, the only problem is that my responsive settings are broken. Inputs are too large in full screen. Even if I shrink it, this time it looks bad in small sizes.

Comment: @İbrahimKoçal That's a separate issue that can be fixed easily as well: If you put the classes for width (`col-4` etc) on the input and combine that with the breakpoint classes (`col-lg-4`, `col-md-6`, `col-sm-12`) you can increase the size of the input per breakpoint.

Comment: yes, I just solved my problem by trying these. thanks

Comment: No problem! You can mark this answer as the one that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer and upvote if you want.